# C code Ghidra decompile results in syntax I am unfamiliar with

Tags: c, ghidra

I am working on reversing a simple binary using Ghidra. The decompile results in this line of code

`if ((param_1 != 4) && (func0(param_1 + 1), param_1 + 1 == 0x32))`
The param_1+1==0x32 section is confusing me as I'm just not familiar with the syntax and am not sure what it is doing inside a boolean expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the comma operator. In this case, it's just unnecessarily confusing, as an alternative decompilation could have avoided it, e.g., these are equivalent:

```
if ((param_1 != 4) && (func0(param_1 + 1), param_1 + 1 == 0x32)) {
    doStuff();
}
```

```
if (param_1 != 4) {
    func0(param_1 + 1);
    if(param_1 + 1 == 0x32) {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is going to be quite the breakdown

The expression is:

```
(func0(param_1 + 1), param_1 + 1 == 0x32)
```

Thus, call func0 with `param_1 + 1`, throw away the result, and compare `param_1 + 1` to `0x32`.

This code is unnatural; I would normally expect to find `param_1 == 0x31`.

I'm guessing that this isn't a C binary and the decompiler can't express pass by value return, which is what ancient basic used. The documentation *says* it's pass by reference, but it is not. I found out the hard way by passing a global to a function that mutated the global.